# How can I access to the serverside php from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, server

I set some variables in serverside through `PHP`

```
$LGD_AMOUNT = ""; //Amount is for the price that customer purchases
$LGD_BUYER = "";//Buyer collect name of the customer
```

And I store these in `$payReqMap`

```
$payReqMap['LGD_AMOUNT'] = $LGD_AMOUNT;
$payReqMap['LGD_BUYER'] = $LGD_BUYER;
```

what I want to do is before I send these to the server side, in `<script>` part, I want to give them values. Is there any method that I can call these stored variables in `<script>` part?

Comment: if you want to use pure javascript, you have to use AJAX using xmlHttpRequest...

Comment: Learn [**AJAX**](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a start point to use Ajax using pure Javascript;

```
function getxmlhttp (){
    //Create a boolean variable to check for a valid Microsoft active x instance.
    var xmlhttp = false;
    //Check if we are using internet explorer.

    try {
        //If the javascript version is greater than 5.
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }

    catch (e) {
        //If not, then use the older active x object.
        try {
            //If we are using internet explorer.
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (E) {
            //Else we must be using a non-internet explorer browser.
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }

    // If not using IE, create a
    // JavaScript instance of the object.
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}//Function getxmlhttp()

//Function to process an XMLHttpRequest.
function processajax (serverPage, obj, getOrPost, str){
    //Get an XMLHttpRequest object for use.
    xmlhttp = getxmlhttp ();

    if (getOrPost == "get"){

        xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send(null);

    }

    else {
        xmlhttp.open("POST", serverPage, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send(str);
    }
}
```